# adding a new row only when the last row in modified

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js

**Problem description:**

I have a table with three rows. The first row contains a drop down. When a user selects a drop down option, a new row should be generated beneath the current last row. How can I tweak this code to such that a new row is generated only when the user selects a drop down option of the current last row, and not any other row?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JPVUk/13/

```
 var ViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
 self.items = ko.observableArray([{comment:'first comment', amount:0}]);
 self.addNewItem = function(){
   self.items.push(new Item('',0));
 };
}

var Item = function(comment, amount) {
var self = this;
self.comment = ko.observable(comment);
self.amount = ko.observable(amount);   
}; 

vm = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**What I am struggling to do:**

So, since I want to bind the change event to the last row, here's how I am approaching it:

```
 <select class="input-small" data-bind="items()[items.length-1] ? event: { change: $root.addNewItem }">
```

This is however not working. Any ideas folks ?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your last question?

Comment: Absolutely, I wanted to create a separate question since I realized that it was deviating from my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/JPVUk/14/

I'm not sure if jQuery was acceptable so this just uses DOM. Basically use the event object passed to knockout. Traverse a little dom and determine is the event target is a child of the last row in the parent table:

```
    var tableRow = event.target.parentNode.parentNode,
        body = tableRow.parentNode,
        nodes = body.childNodes,
        children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        // remove non-element node types. ie textNodes, etc.
        if (nodes[i].nodeType === 1) {
            children.push(nodes[i]);
        }
    }

    if (tableRow === children[children.length - 1]) {
        self.items.push(new Item('', 0));
    }
```

Comment: this is a very good answer. I was thinking the way Matt answered. So let me implement that, if it does not work, then I will definitely go with this answer.

Comment: Kinda misses the point of using an MVVM framework like knockout in the first place.

Comment: @MattBurland, you are absolutely correct. Stranger, I would suggest using Matt's answer over mine. If you were to change the DOM, you would have to change this method.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just past the row that causes the event to fire to your handler and check it there?

Something like this:

```
<select class="input-small" data-bind="event: { change: $root.addNewItem }">
```

And then:

```
self.addNewItem = function(row){
    if (row == self.items()[self.items().length - 1]) {
        self.items.push(new Item('',0));
    }
};
```

Comment: can you help me out here? I have implemented your idea but looks like something's still wrong. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JPVUk/15/